# Emacs: how to set home environment dependent on username

Tags: emacs, initialization, synchronization, environment-variables

I have installed emacs on two different computers, on computer A at home and on computer B at my job. In order to sync the setting of these two installations, I have moved my `.emacs.d` folder to dropbox and on each computer symlinked this folder to the folder `C:/Users/myLogonName/AppData/Roaming/` on each of the two computer.

However, `myLogonName` is defined differently on the two computers, respectively as `myLogonNameA` and `myLogonNameB`. This gives me a practical problem when emacs read the `init.el` file which begins with defining the home environment with this line:

```
(setenv "HOME" "C:/Users/myLogonName/AppData/Roaming/")
```

If `myLogonName` in this line is set to `myLogonNameA`, the definition will function on computer A, but not on computer B. And similarly if `myLogonName` is set to `myLogonNameB`, the definition will function on computer B, but not on computer A.

I need a conditional definition of the home environment, something like the folllowing pseudo code:

```
if computer == computerA
    (setenv "HOME" "C:/Users/myLogonNameA/AppData/Roaming/")
elseif computer == computerB
    (setenv "HOME" "C:/Users/myLogonNameB/AppData/Roaming/")
end
```

How do I make such a conditional definition of the home environment ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Setting HOME inside emacs sounds really strange. Since you don't seem to be afraid of pragmatic hacks, maybe just create a symlink for the HOME directory of the non-existing user?

Comment: Agree with @maxy: HOME is useful outside of emacs, so you should probably set it in an environment initiailzation file (btw, why is it not set already?) and let emacs inherit it from the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs variable `user-login-name` holds your login name.

You can use code like this in your init file, to distinguish the different user names:

```
(setenv "HOME" 
        (if (string-match-p user-login-name "myLogonName-A")
            "C:/Users/myLogonName-A/AppData/Roaming/"
          "C:/Users/myLogonName-B/AppData/Roaming/"))
```

or if it's as simple as that then just this:

```
(setenv "HOME" (format "C:/Users/%s/AppData/Roaming/" user-login-name))
```